# Using streams between Delphi and C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll, stream

As I understand it, I can use TStreamAdapter to create an IStream of a TMemoryStream and pass that as a parameter to a C# function, and can also use TOleStream to turn an IStream into a TMemoryStream.

What I cannot seem to find is what type I should be using in the C# DLL so that when it is imported into XE2, the Delphi type library has IStream as the type.

When I build my C# DLL that includes System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream as a parameter, the compiler shows a warning:

> Warning: Type library exporter could not find the type library for
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream'.  IUnknown was
>   substituted for the interface.

However, if I use a Stream data type in C# and import into Delphi, that comes across as a _Stream, which I believe is defined in mscorlib.

Would this be the best way to handle data traffic between a Delphi DLL and a .NET DLL?

Comment: Can you show the code for your exported COM class? Perhaps even an MCVE that we could work on.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Did you try it? If C# passes an `IUnknown` that offers a `IStream` when asked to, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've used a workaround for the moment but will revisit this when I have time.